# Order data coming from an api

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I was wondering if there is a way to order data coming from an api? I'm getting a list of items from an api and I want to push the items that contains a specific key in its object at the end of the list, and just leave the items that doesn't contain that key as they are, is there a way that I can do that from the client side?

```
{this.state.items.map(i => <Item key={i.id}  button={this.state.button} id={i.id} name={i.name} price={i.price} quantity={i.quantity} />)}
```

Comment: Please share your code you currently have and please be more specific how your end result should look like

Comment: But yes, you could retrieve a list of items, save some of the items keys in another list and send this to where ever you want.

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm trying to do is that for example if I'm getting these two item objects {name: example, img: "", id: "", someKey: ""}, {name: example, img: "", id: ""}. by default the items will show in the same order as they are. but what I want to do is that I want the object that contains "someKey", to show up after the item that doesn't contain that key.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `sort` method on arrays.

Comment: You could sort the array after that attribute. Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/1625253